# How to run count.index for limited indexes in terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Is there any way where count.index can be run for some index values and not for all the values in list.
I have a list variable

```
variable "subnets_cidr" {
    type = list
    default = ["172.17.1.0/24", "172.17.2.0/24", "172.17.3.0/24","172.17.10.0/24","172.17.11.0/24","172.17.12.0/24"]
}
```

and a subnet

```
    # Subnets : Public
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count = length(var.subnets_cidr)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.terra_vpc.id
  cidr_block = element(var.subnets_cidr,count.index)
  availability_zone = element(var.azs,count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = element(var.pub_sub_names, count.index)
  }
}
```

With the above code 6 subnets are being created, but i dont want that,i want to limit to create only 3 subnets.
I was thinking to slice the count.index variable like count.index[1:3] but it not working.

also with the below code for route table association, it associating all the subnets but here also i would like to limit the number of subnets. for e.g say first 3 subnets.

```
# Route table association with public subnets
resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  count = length(var.subnets_cidr)
  subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.public.*.id,count.index)
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_rt.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using count, you can use locals for different subnets
use subnetone for one range of subnets and subnettwo for other subnet ranges

```
locals {
 teams = {
  "subnetone" = {
    subnet1 = "172.17.1.0/24"
    subnet2 = "172.17.2.0/24"
    subnet3 = "172.17.3.0/24"
  },
  "subnettwo" = {
     subnet4 = "172.17.10.0/24"
     subnet5 = "172.17.11.0/24"
     subnet6 = "172.17.12.0/24"
  } 
}
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each = local.teams.subnetone
  cidr_block = each.value
  vpc_id = "vpc-09c37360e8b599296"
}
```